# Why won't CSS work when I have #id #id?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I can't seem to get my CSS to link to a div when I use:

```
[in stylesheet(style.css)]

#sitecontainer .header {
    background-image:url('/images/header-background');
}


<div id="sitecontainer">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

However when I place the CSS inline in the page it does work. Any ideas?

Pete

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your CSS is using a class selector on header:

```
.header
```

rather than.

```
#header
```

This would work if you had HTML mark-up like this:

```
<div id="sitecontainer">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

But in your case you could use:

```
#sitecontainer #header
```

or even better (unless you're doing something very specific in your site with this particular header) you should just cut it down to

```
#header { /* CSS rules here */ }
```

For more info - [A really good article of the various CSS selection methods is here on NetTuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/).

Comment: In my opinion header, content and footer are pretty generic layout elements. they might show up again deeper nested in your page. example: your site has a header, content and footer and in your content maybe you want to show some text document which in itself also has a header, content and footer so semantically I think classes are a better approach.

Comment: I tend to agree. With HTML5 header, footer and article are all repeatable elements and so to have similar semantics, classes are the way to go.

Comment: I still prefer to give my primary header and footer the id of header and footer, sub headers and footers can have a class.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `#` in both places:

```
#sitecontainer #header {
  background-image:url('/images/header-background');
}
```

Make sure your IDs are unique in the page though, or this will cause other issues.  If you have multiple headers then *do* use a `class` attribute instead:

```
<div id="sitecontainer">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

...and use your current CSS with the `.header` class selector.

Comment: @Harmen - It could be, but assuming the obvious isn't the problem will only cause endless headaches, solve the obvious, *then* see if it's still broken :) The code in the question doesn't work...*never* assume it's "just a typo", many, *many*, **many** programming problems are typos.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `#header` - as it is an id, it should already be unique (edit: as long as there aren't other pages where you don't want this to happen and don't hava a `sitecontainer`).

Comment: While it should be unique in the page, it may not be unique across *all* pages.  For example what if the OP had `<div id="othercontainer"><div id="header"></div></div>` on another page that shouldn't be styled?

Comment: @Nick Craver: Hmm, that's right. I was assuming that he named the container `sitecontainer` on all pages.